# How to add something to start of url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have seen sites that when you login it will look something like...

```
 .example.localhost/blahblah.php
```

how is this possible with htaccess?

Any ideas

Do the files have to be placed in a seperate folder??

Answer (score 0):

It's called sub-domain.

It has more to do with the DNS but htaccess can be used to modified its behavior.

Ie, point different sub-domain to the same folder.